How do I properly chroot from a amd64 artix VM into a mounted aarch64 armtix OS image?
I want to chroot into an armtix (aarch64) OS image inside an artix VM.
I copied qemu-aarch64-static into the mounted /usr/bin
and then tried to chroot into the mounted image.
It works, however, most programs don't.
Below is my attempt:
$ artix-chroot /var/tmp/eqstalxr-bastij/root qemu-aarch64-static /bin/bash
bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
[bastille-installer /]# ls                                                                                                                                                                     
bash: /usr/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
[bastille-installer /]# cat                                                                                                                                                                    
bash: /usr/bin/cat: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
[bastille-installer /]# dir                                                                                                                                                                    
bash: /usr/bin/dir: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
[bastille-installer /]# cd .                                                                                                                                                                   
[bastille-installer /]# cd bin                                                                                                                                                                 
[bastille-installer bin]# cd ..                                                                                                                                                                
[bastille-installer /]# exit     

Is this how far I can go with it or are there ways to make other
programs work as well.
I need pacman, tee, sed, cp and other installation commands to work on it,
as I want to later move the customized image to my sd card.
[edit]
$ file /var/tmp/eqstalxr-bastij/root/bin/bash
/var/tmp/eqstalxr-bastij/root/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, BuildID[sha1]=134f0d233c131cc03b87ed000859f62805ead4ca, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, stripped

ls works via this command, however pacman-key doesn't.
$ artix-chroot /var/tmp/eqstalxr-bastij/root qemu-aarch64-static /bin/ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
$ artix-chroot /var/tmp/eqstalxr-bastij/root qemu-aarch64-static /bin/pacman-key
Error while loading /usr/bin/pacman-key: Exec format error
$ file /var/tmp/eqstalxr-bastij/root/bin/pacman-key
/var/tmp/eqstalxr-bastij/root/bin/pacman-key: a /usr/sbin/bash script, ASCII text executable


From outside the chroot, what does file /var/tmp/eqstalxr-bastij/root/bin/bash say? From inside the chroot what does qemu-aarch64-static /bin/ls say?

Ohhhh.... I need to add qemu-aarch64-static to every command. Thanks. I still have issues with pacman-key.

As I thought, you do need to add qemu-aarch64-static to every binary command.Can you tell us what file /var/tmp/eqstalxr-bastij/root/bin/pacman-key says?

Yes. I re-edited my OP post. Last two lines.

"I need to add qemu-aarch64-static to every command." You shouldn't. If you set up binfmt_misc correctly, the kernel will do that for you automatically. Most distributions do this for you automatically when you install the qemu-user-... packages. This also means you don't need to put the qemu-user binaries inside the chroot. You can save yourself a bunch of effort if you configure this correctly.

So pacman-key is a bash script, and not an arm binary. This means that you need to have it invoked by bash, not directly by qemu-aarch64-static. Of course if you are going to use the arm version of bash from your image,then that bash is going to need to be invoked using qemu-aarch64-static. @larsks has beaten me to the punchline that you can probably set this all up automatically using the kernel facilities for starting programs.

Okay, it looks like I had to follow this documentation: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.rst and restart the binfmt service
